# Embed frame of a local .exe in a web browser

Tags: html, browser, exe

The question may sound a little odd but I'm currently in a project where this could help solving many problems.
Is it somehow possible to embed an .exe into any web browser? I don't want to run the program directly in the browser (would be major security risk I guess), I just want the window of the .exe being embeded into a browser page. So the .exe is running locally on the system but instead of a "windows window" I have it displayed in the web browser. Think of it like VNC, I only need my "video" and the possiblity of user interaction (the program is an interactive 3D visualization).

I don't have much hope for this being possible so I'm also glad about any suggestion that would allow me to display web pages while my program is running in the same (fullscreen) window. Doesn't necessarily has to be a "real" browser but should allow basic stuff like HTML, CSS etc.

Comment: [Another question on SO](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/527121/how-run-exe-game-inside-a-webpage) involving an "exe game" (really executables, in general) should provide some answers for you.

Comment: Thanks that is very helpful! :)
I wonder why the search didn't gave me that question.

Answer (score 0):

This kinda sound more like a SuperUser question rather than a StackOverflow one.

Anyway, I have a number of possible solutions for you:

1. You could use a second monitor.
2. Maybe all you really need is setting the "exe" window to "always be on top".
   I could swear that used to be an option in the Windows' default Task Manager in the earlier versions of Windows but I use a 3rd-party piece of software for around 10 years now for that and many other purposes, however there are many such options to be found online.
   *Can't risk endorsing the one I use here, since it tends to spook people into thinking I'm trying to infect them with HAX.*
3. In case you have the sources for the "exe" you are running, have you considered going the other way around and building a web renderer into your desktop program? Something like WebKit, Servo and suchlike.
   *Or you could make the program listen on a port to network packets you can be sending from the page you'd have to make — like a remote control.

   Then there's also the cgi-bin option if you run the server.

   And, to see what you're controlling, you might wanna stream it to some streaming platform (if you get it to stream an obscured window), embed their player widget in an `iframe` on your custom local webpage and keep the website you are reaching in another frame.

   Maybe even code the program to read XInput and stream it through Mixer using its MixPlay feature to control it.*

Hope any of this helps.